# subquery into where doctrine 2?

Tags: mysql, doctrine-orm, zend-framework2, subquery

I have a little problem trying to implement a subquery within a where. Actually I have no idea who it might be. Agradesco that I can help beforehand.

This is my QueryBuilder

```
$em = $this->getEntityManager();
$qb = $em->createQueryBuilder();
$qb2 = $em->createQueryBuilder();

$qb->select('pp')
        ->add('from', 'ORM\Entity\PedidoProducto pp')
        ->innerJoin('pp.idPedido', 'pd')
        ->innerJoin('pp.idProducto', 'p')
        ->join('ORM\Entity\ProductoCompra', 'pc', 'WITH', 'pc.idProducto = p.id')
        ->where($qb->expr()->eq('pc.idCompra', $qb2->select('MAX(pc1.idCompra)')
                ->add('from', 'ORM\Entity\ProductoCompra pc1')
                ->where('pc1.idProducto = pc.idProducto')
                ->groupBy('pc1.idProducto')->getDQL()))
    ->groupBy('pc.idProducto');
```

And this is the query:

```
SELECT * 
FROM pedido_producto pp 
INNER JOIN pedido pd ON pp.id_pedido = pd.id
INNER JOIN producto p ON pp.id_producto = p.id
INNER JOIN producto_compra pc ON pc.id_producto = p.id
WHERE pc.id_compra = (
SELECT max(pc1.id_compra) 
FROM producto_compra pc1 
WHERE pc.id_producto = pc1.id_producto
GROUP BY pc1.id_producto) GROUP BY pc.id_producto
```

This is the error:

```
Doctrine\ORM\Query\QueryException

File:

    C:\xampp\htdocs\ventasV1\vendor\doctrine\orm\lib\Doctrine\ORM\Query\QueryException.php:52

Message:

    [Syntax Error] line 0, col 183: Error: Expected Literal, got 'SELECT'
```

I hope and I can help you solve it.
Thank you.

Comment: What about a native query ? http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/native-sql.html

Comment: From your qb2, maybe you have to use getSQL instead of getDQL, give it a try please

Comment: Thank you very much for your response.
  @ceadreak And had actually done and it works, but I wanted to try to QueryBuilder.

Comment: Thank you very much for your response.                                                  @Hooli He had not tested as you say, I'll do it later and comment as I was.